# Has anyone ever actually considered a spherical cow?

Tags: simulations, approximations, biology, models

Yes, I'm aware this question is somewhat whimsical.

I'm sure every physicist is familiar with ["Consider a Spherical cow"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow).

Has a cow (or any animal for that matter) ever been assumed spherical for any serious scientific publication?

I'd consider a simulation where the cow is abstracted as a particle with a given radius as spherical.

Comment: I think spherical animals might implicitly show up in some computational biology - it is certainly common to assume cells to be spheres, and many models treat animals (incorrectly) as well-mixed volumes that might well be spherical. I did find one paper comparing spherical cows to more realistic cows for computational fluid dynamics: https://elibrary.asabe.org/abstract.asp?aid=46263

Comment: In addition, there is no shortage of papers referring to "consider a spherical cow" - it is a common warning in computational biology not to do it (so common that I suspect the practice is widespread).

Comment: A cow zygote might be spherical...

Comment: Interesting that this was put on hold as too broad. *Put on hold as Off-topic* I can understand, but I'm not sure what one would do to narrow the question. "Consider a spherical Holstein cow"?